# How to process signals in a Qt subclass?

Tags: c++, qt, overriding, subclass, signals-slots

How do I process a signal of in a subclass?  Let's say my subclass is derived from `QTextEdit` and is interested in the signal `textChanged`.  It seems silly to connect an object to itself, I should be able to simply override the `textChange` method -- but it isn't `virtual`.

What is the accepted way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't implement/override a signal, so the only way is to create a new slot and connect it to textChanged():

```
connect( this, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(slotTextChanged(QString)) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it seems silly, but that's the way I did it : connecting my derived class to the signal emited by the parent class.

But I'm interested if there are any other solutions !

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly ok to connect a signal to a slot in the same class.
So implement your slot and connect it to `textChanged(QString)`